# Calculating Percentage using Case(Text(TERR2_NAME:UNIQUE

Tags: formula, dashboard

I have a valid summary formula that I am attempting to incorporate into my dashboard to show percentages based on what is in the system and how many records should be in the system. My formula is:

Name: Current Market
Description: Shows the total % of the market uploaded.
Percentage: 2 decimal places

```
Case(
    TEXT(TERR2_NAME:UNIQUE),
    "Territory1", RowCount / 3000,
    "Territory2", RowCount / 4000,
    "Territory3", RowCount / 5000,
    0
)
```

When I create the dashboard, it shows total records with a percent sign instead of the actual division properties.

I have ensured that the unique is case-sensitive and matches the correct spelling.

I have also done `(RowCount / 3000) * 100`, etc... to no avail. I have tried doing `TERR2_Name__c` and get invalid properties. I am wondering if I should try an `ISPICKVAL()` or `PARENTGROUPVAL()` instead. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create row level formula.

```
Case(TERR2_NAME__c,
     "Territory 1", 3000,
     "Territory 2", 4000,
     "Territory 3", 5000,
0
)
```

Create Summary formula column

```
RowCount/"NameOfYourRowLevelFormula:Avg
```